# Please help me to check the session errors in my login

Tags: php, session

after form submission form session will be saved into variables by session variable we can check right. but when i checked it out it was displaying the error

```
    <?php
    include '../includes/config.php';
    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $pass = $_POST['password'];
        $msg = "The email or password you entered is incorrect"; //error message

        //email validation
        if(empty($email) || empty($pass)){
            echo $msg;
            header ("refresh:5; url=index.php");
            exit();
        }

        if(!preg_match('/@/',$email)){
            echo $msg;
            header ("refresh:5; url=index.php");
            exit();
        }

        //search username and password from table users
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table_users");
        $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result);

        if($email == $fetch['email'] && $pass == $fetch['pass']){
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email'] = $result['email'];
            $_SESSION['type'] = $result['type'];
            header('refresh:2; url=../panel/index.php');
            echo "Logged in..";
            exit();
        }
        else
            echo $msg;
            header ("refresh:5; url=index.php");
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location:../index.php');
    }
?>
```

This is admin code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Hotel Administration</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../css/system.css" />
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['email']))
    {
        die("The user must be logged in");
    }
?>
</head>

<body>
```

i have a problem to check out the session in adminpage.. it was saying session error message help me out

Comment: What is the actual error message?

Comment: I think you need session variables are not properly set because mysqli_fetch_array expects one more parameter MYSQLI_ASSOC for accessing data by columns name or the other parameter to access data by index no.

Comment: i was getting this session error message

Comment: omitting MYSQLI_ASSOC gives acess to a single column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_users
```

thats a really bad idea, guess what happens when there are ~5k users at some time
better do

```
SELECT 1 FROM table_users WHERE username LIKE "$user" AND password = MD5("$password") LIMIT 1;
```

besides that i'd recommend to use curly blocks at else

```
if(!empty($fetch))
{
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['email'] = $result['email'];
        $_SESSION['type'] = $result['type'];
        header('refresh:2; url=../panel/index.php');
        echo "Logged in..";
        exit();
  }
  else
  {
        echo $msg;
        header ("refresh:5; url=index.php");
  }
```

Comment: Great now OP is vulnerable to SQL injection. Also `md5` is in no way suitable for hashing passwords.

Comment: @cpfaffinger cheers!! buddy this worked out for my log in part